# module module class vs. module module::class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module

What is the difference between

```
module MyModule
  module MySubModule
    class MySubModuleClass
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
module MyModule
  class MySubModule::MySubModuleClass
    ...
  end
end
```

in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second case will not work unless "MySubModule" is already defined elsewhere...

the second case is not a proper definition of "MySubModule" and will cause an error if you didn't define that MySubModule elsewhere

```
NameError: uninitialized constant MyModule::MySubModule
    from (irb):2:in `<module:MyModule>'
```

Answer (score 1):

On the second example you are defining a `class`, in the first is a `module`, and you can't use the syntax `MySubModule::MySubModuleClass` if `MySubModule` does not exist. So you have to have it defined before.

Comment: Crap..I meant to use "class" for the first example. I've corrected the question...